# setup moddable for esp32 on ubuntu20.4

Tags: esp32

I try to setup moddable for esp32 chip on Ubuntu. I followed steps as described in Moddable-OpenSource.The final result I got is as follow.

```
Serial port /dev/ttyS0
Connecting..............
Chip is ESP32-D0WD-V3 (revision 3)
Features: WiFi, BT, Dual Core, 240MHz, VRef calibration in efuse, Coding Scheme None
Crystal is 40MHz
MAC: cc:db:a7:16:2f:34
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Configuring flash size...
Flash will be erased from 0x00001000 to 0x00005fff...
Flash will be erased from 0x00010000 to 0x00069fff...
Flash will be erased from 0x00008000 to 0x00008fff...
Compressed 17488 bytes to 12196...
Writing at 0x00001000... (100 %)
Wrote 17488 bytes (12196 compressed) at 0x00001000 in 3.7 seconds (effective 37.4 kbit/s)...
Hash of data verified.
Compressed 367424 bytes to 216224...
Writing at 0x00010000... (7 %)
Writing at 0x0001a3b6... (14 %)
Writing at 0x00024cdb... (21 %)
Writing at 0x0002a113... (28 %)
Writing at 0x000306bc... (35 %)
Writing at 0x000359e7... (42 %)
Writing at 0x0003b1c5... (50 %)
Writing at 0x00040a9e... (57 %)
Writing at 0x00046b11... (64 %)
Writing at 0x0004d98d... (71 %)
Writing at 0x00052c70... (78 %)
Writing at 0x00057f1a... (85 %)
Writing at 0x0005e0f3... (92 %)
Writing at 0x0006872a... (100 %)
Wrote 367424 bytes (216224 compressed) at 0x00010000 in 59.7 seconds (effective 49.3 kbit/s)...
Hash of data verified.
Compressed 3072 bytes to 123...
Writing at 0x00008000... (100 %)
Wrote 3072 bytes (123 compressed) at 0x00008000 in 0.1 seconds (effective 227.1 kbit/s)...
Hash of data verified.

Leaving...
Hard resetting via RTS pin...
Executing action: flash
Running ninja in directory /home/sila/Projects/moddable/build/tmp/esp32/debug/helloworld/xsProj-esp32/build
Executing "ninja flash"...
Done
ets Jul 29 2019 12:21:46
rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0030,len:344
load:0x40078000,len:13544
load:0x40080400,len:3512
entry 0x400805d0
```

I guess the flash procedure was completed but it stopped there.Any help would be appreciate. Thank

I try with hello world example. it work if I try using simulator using
mcconfig -d -m

Comment: Hi Sila, welcome to SO. Please add some details to your post - what is the command you're executing, which ESP32 devkit you're running, what's the expected outcome and what happens instead.

Comment: I setup moddable according to https://github.com/Moddable-OpenSource/moddable/blob/public/documentation/Moddable%20SDK%20-%20Getting%20Started.md and https://github.com/Moddable-OpenSource/moddable/blob/public/documentation/Moddable%20SDK%20-%20Getting%20Started.md

Comment: https://github.com/Moddable-OpenSource/moddable/blob/public/documentation/Moddable%20SDK%20-%20Getting%20Started.md

Comment: finally i run mcconfig -d -m -p esp32/nodemcu. I use Node MCU ESP32.